# Adding dylib to Application Bundle in Mac OS X

Tags: java, xcode, macos, javafx-8, app-bundle

We are developing a JavaFx application on Mac Platform that requires interfacing of HID devices. We have chosen HID4Java(https://github.com/gary-rowe/hid4java/) for the purpose. The application is running fine when we are running from the netbeans but when we create Application bundle (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html) of the same it stop working.

We have placed the dylib file in the Framework directory. Have tried to register it using the install_name_tool and otool, but nothing works can anybody help

Comment: Could you provide some code-sample for this? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: thanks #FibreFox but the problem was resolved using the OneJar